# Would like to output xml file as in body from python using lxml

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

Would like to output the following at the head of xml

I can find lots on parsing and validating, but not so much on creation/output

I can find some documentation on QName but how do I output

`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
 <gdml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     

 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://service-spi.web.cern.ch/service-spi/app  /releases/GDML/schema/gdml.xsd">`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`QName`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.QName-class.html) to create the attribute (`noNamespaceSchemaLocation`) that is bound to the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` namespace.

```
from lxml.etree import QName, Element, tostring

qname = QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation")
attr_dict = {qname: "http://service-spi.web.cern.ch/service-spi/app /releases/GDML/schema/gdml.xsd"}

gdml = Element("gdml", attr_dict)

print(tostring(gdml, encoding="UTF-8", standalone=False).decode())
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<gdml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://service-spi.web.cern.ch/service-spi/app /releases/GDML/schema/gdml.xsd"/>
```

The namespace declaration (`xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`) is created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - I already did it another way

```
  NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
  location_attribute = '{%s}noNameSpaceSchemaLocation' % NS
  gdml = ET.Element('gdml',attrib={location_attribute:   'http://service-spi.web.cern.ch/service-spi/app/releases/GDML/schema/gdml.xsd'})
  print(gdml.tag)
```